# Mechanize Not Finding Forms

Tags: python, python-2.7, mechanize

So I'm trying to login to a page (https://rally1.rallydev.com) using Mechanize and it is not finding any forms.

```
import mechanize
import urllib2 
import cookielib

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.open('https://rally1.rallydev.com/')
for form in br.forms():
    print form.name
```

Running this returns nothing at all.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I am new to Mechanize and cannot find similar issues online.

Comment: It's not `BeautifulSoup` not finding forms, it's mechanize.

Comment: My bad, I meant mechanize. Edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a redirect is occurring that mechanize isn't handling (perhaps it is occurring in Javascript?).

Try to go straight to the login page by specifying this url: https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/login.op